# Tactile Learning Activities in Mathematics

Tags: undergraduate-education, recreational-learning

> Julie Barnes, Jessica M. Libertini. *Tactile Learning Activities in Mathematics: A Recipe Book for the Undergraduate Classroom*.
>   2018. MAA Press.
>   [AMS Bookstore link](https://bookstore.ams.org/clrm-54).

Can anyone comment / review this collection? Perhaps too new for published reviews...

---

[image: Cover]

---

Comment: Are you considering getting it? If you offer to review it, they might be happy to send you a free copy.

Comment: @SueVanHattum: Good point! But, alas, my job would preclude reviewing for some time.

Comment: It looks interesting. If I knew I'd have time to write a review, I'd send them a request for a review copy myself.